# I can't find which Tomcat m2e is running

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2e

In Eclipse, I have a Maven project which is a web app. When I click on Run -> Maven build (and inside the run configuration I have set the tomcat:run goal), a Tomcat is started. The problem is, I see in the console that the tomcat that starts is version 6 and since I haven't installed any Tomcat 6 in my machine, I don't know where Maven is getting this tomcat from.
I'd like Maven to start a tomcat 8 instead of 6 but I don't know where this can be configured.

I don't have anything related to tomcat in my pom.xml.

The console outputs this:

```
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\user\workspace\myapp\target\tomcat
oct 21, 2016 3:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting tomcat server
oct 21, 2016 3:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

But as I said, I don't know where the tomcat 6 is. I haven't installed it myself and I don't know where it comes from. My guess is that it's a Tomcat that comes embedded with m2e but I am at a loss here.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide these informations: console output, pom.xml

Comment: did you set the environment variable CATALINA_HOME ? Does PATH include the Tomcat bin-directory?

Comment: @JimHawkins No, and no :) I have added more information about the pom.xml and the console.

Comment: you've written "_Run -> Maven build (and inside the run configuration I have set the tomcat:run goal)_" . So I reasoned you've configured the tomcat7-maven-plugin (works with Tomcat 8, too)

Comment: in eclipse, open the _Preferences_ dialog. Go to to section _Server_ --> _Runtime Environment_ . Are there Tomcat servers listed?

Comment: @JimHawkins no, I haven't configured anything related to tomcat in the pom.xml. In Runtime Environment I only have a Tomcat 8 (which is the one I have downloaded and installed manually to my machine)

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your tomcat in eclipse IDE, then you'll see in the servers tab.
You need to indicate to eclipse which configuration they must use. [image]

Comment: Yes, I have a tomcat 8 configured in the Servers tab, that's why I don't understand why maven runs an instance of a Tomcat 6.

Comment: Yes, it is. Regardless, this is about the tomcat 8 while what I am trying to find is the location of the tomcat 6